# How to find if strings from one Pandas Series are in another Series as substrings?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 Pandas dataframes:

```
df1:

   name    exchange
0  bob     Bobby
1  toon    Looney Tunes
2  donal   Donald Duck


df2:
    strings
0   watching toon
1   love donal
2   nice bobguy
```

What I want to achieve is to go through df2 rows, and check each value if contains df1['name'] values. If it does contain, replace df1['name'] with df1['exchange'] in df2.
The output should be:

```
df2:
    strings
0   watching Looney Toons
1   love Donald Duck
2   nice Bobbyguy
```

What I tried to do so far is:

```
    for row_index, row in df2.iterrows():
        for row_alias_index, row_alias in df1.iterrows():
            if row_alias['name'] in row['strings']:
                df2.at[row_index, 'strings'] = row['strings'].replace(row_alias['name'], row['exchange'])
                break
```

I have a large number of df1 rows, and do not think 2 for loops are a way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) by `Series` with `regex=True` for subtrings replacement:

```
df2['strings'] = df2['strings'].replace(df1.set_index('name')['exchange'], regex=True)
print (df2)
                 strings
0  watching Looney Tunes
1       love Donald Duck
2          nice Bobbyguy
```

If want also replace values if exist test rows by [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with `|` for regex `OR` and apply solution only for matching rows:

```
s = df1.set_index('name')['exchange']
m = df2['strings'].str.contains('|'.join(s.index))
print (m)
0    True
1    True
2    True
Name: strings, dtype: bool

df2.loc[m, 'strings'] = df2.loc[m, 'strings'].replace(s, regex=True)
print (df2)
                 strings
0  watching Looney Tunes
1       love Donald Duck
2          nice Bobbyguy
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is correct, but check out this example:

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'name':['bob', 'bobby'], 'exchange':['Bobby', 'BOBBY']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'strings':['cool bob', 'heybobby']}).

The output is:

0    cool Bobby
1    heyBobbyby.

I understand what happened with heyBobbyby. How can I avoid it?

Comment: @page47250 - It should be only possible if `hey bobby` instead `heybobby` - each value for repalce should be around spaces in data, in real data are no spaces areound words for replace?

Comment: In real data I have situation like this:
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'name':['have', 'behave'], 'exchange':['Have', 'Behave']}). I get beHave for output and would like Behave.

Comment: @page47250 - so each value is separate `,` ?

Comment: @page47250 - I think like `df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'strings':['cool,bob', 'hey,bobby']}) `

Comment: They are not separated. I have two words, "have" and in different row "behave". I wish to get "Have" and "Behave". The thing I get is "Have" and "beHave". In the second word, just the "have" part of "behave" is replaced.

Comment: @page47250 - undertand, btw, what is size of both DataFrames?

Comment: Both frames have number of rows over 5000.

Comment: @page47250 - I found solution (I hope), can you test it? Only sorted `df1` by lengths of `strings` for replace, reason is first repalce longer strings, then shorter. Add `df1 = df1.iloc[(-df1['name'].str.len()).argsort()]` before my both solutions.

Comment: tested in python `3.7.4` under pandas `0.25.1` and win7

Comment: Do not know for sure, but I think something might be wrong with the sorting? I do not get the longest name on top of the df1. At least, not in my real DataFrame.

Comment: @page47250 - So not working `df1 = df1.iloc[(-df1['name'].str.len()).argsort()]` ?

Comment: I'll try some more, but when I check visually, the strings are not sorted wrt length.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209157/discussion-between-page47250-and-jezrael).